# Finding most recent file in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have to find the most recent file in a directory. I have used the code below that works fine for recent file, but my problem is that there are two files generated with same time stamp e.g.

1. `s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW_9_error.csv`
2. `s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW_8_1_2013_14_10_standard_error.csv`

My code is :

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b %1') do set recent=%%x
```

Here I am passing %1% argument as `s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW_9*.csv` to find most recent file. This code returns the most recent file as  `s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW_8_1_2013_14_10_standard_error.csv` but I want the most recent file to be `s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW_9_error.csv`.

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon. Given the wild card expression you say you're passing, how does the file with `_8_` in its name ever get selected?  How do you know that the `_9_` file should be selected in preference to the `_8_` file?  What should happen if there's a file with `_10_` in place of the `_9_`?  Is the criteria based on the name or on the timestamp of the file?

Comment: if two (or more) files have the same time stamp, both (or more) are "most recent".

Comment: your code works. test it at the command line: `for /f "delims=" %x in ('dir /od /a-d /b s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW_9*.csv') do @echo %x`.

Comment: any solution to get s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW_9_error.csv file instead of standard one.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about a few things in your question. If there is a known phrase in the filename you want, you can filter for it with find, like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b ^| find /i "_9_error"') do set recent=%%x
```

Note the ^ to allow use of the pipe.

If the file has known content, you can similarly figure out which one to use using find. If neither the filename nor content has anything to filter for, and the timestamp is the same, you're stuck.

Comment: There is no known phrase in file name . _9_error will not same for next file it will _10_error. This file is auto generated with informatica cloud. I want a for loop that skips file with name contains standard and search for recent file.

Comment: Below batch file works for my solution, just only problem is that copy command not copying file with different name.

Answer (score 0):

I have created below batch script that resolves my problem. only problem is that copy command.

i want to copy filename with different name. that doesn't work.
e.g.  s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW.csv needs to be copied as AAA.csv.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set j=0
SET logdirectory=C:\batchfiles\error
SET logdirectoryBackup=C:\batchfiles\error_processing\
cd "%logdirectory%

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-d s_dss_000GJ00I0000000000IW*.csv') DO (
set /A j=j+1
echo !j!

set tst=%%i
set tst=!tst:standard=!
if not !tst!==%%i ( 
echo %%i contains standard
) else (

echo f|xcopy %%i "%logdirectoryBackup%"AAA.csv /Y
echo %%i not contains standard

)
if !j! geq 2 (

    goto :end
)

)
:end
pause
```